# Daily MySQL Backups to FTP Server

Tags: mysql, windows, service

My customer wants his database to be as reliable as possible, and wishes for daily backups to be made. Since I do not have the time to back the database up daily and upload it to an FTP server, I wonder, is there a windows program which would customize a service to backup a single database and upload it to an FTP server daily or some other alternative I have overlooked?

Comment: How big is the database in T/G/MB... and do you mean SFTP not FTP? As your question stands my answer would be to persuade your customer to change his/her mind.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to backup your database - daily at least!
Here is the way: http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/
Here is a new way (slick new-gen webservice): myrepono.com
Companies large and small lose everything if they lose data.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Navicat for MySQL](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql). You can create a backup schedule in it easily.